# Pass a parameter to Ansible's dynamic inventory

Tags: python, bash, ansible

I'm using Ansible to configure some virtual machines. I wrote a Python script which retrieves the hosts from a REST service.
My VMs are organized in "Environments". For example I have the "Test", "Red" and "Integration" environments, each with a subset of VMs.

This Python script requires the custom `--environment <ENV>` parameter to retrieve the hosts of the wanted environment.

The problem I'm having is passing the `<ENV>` to the `ansible-playbook` command. 
In fact the following command doesn't work

```
ansible-playbook thePlaybook.yml -i ./inventory/FromREST.py --environment Test
```

I get the error:

```
Usage: ansible-playbook playbook.yml

ansible-playbook: error: no such option: --environment
```

What is the right syntax to pass variables to a dynamic inventory script?

Update:

To better explain, the `FromREST.py` script accepts the following parameters:

- Either the `--list` parameter or the `--host <HOST>` parameter, as per the [Dynamic Inventory guidelines](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_inventory.html)
- The `--environment <ENVIRONMENT>`  parameter, which I added to the ones required by Ansible to manage the different Environments

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue, I didn't find any solution, so I just modified my dynamic inventory to use OS Environment variable if the user does not pass `--env`

**Capture env var in your inventory as below:**

```
import os
print os.environ['ENV']
```

**Pass env var to ansible**

```
export ENV=dev
ansible -i my_custom_inv.py all --list-host
```

Answer (score 3):

A workaround using `$PPID` to parse `-e`/`--extra-vars` from process snapshot.

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.sh deploy.yml -e cluster=cl_01
```

`inventory.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 != "--list" ]]; then exit 1; fi
extra_var=`ps -f -p $PPID | grep ansible-playbook | grep -oh "\w*=\w*" | grep cluster | cut -f2 -d=`
./inventory.py --cluster $extra_var
```

`inventory.py` returns `JSON` inventory for cluster `cl_01`.

Not pretty I know, but works.